# Get function that returns expandable connector variable names and/or number of connector variables?

Tags: modelica

Does Modelica have get function that returns the variable names and/or the number of variables of an expandable connector?

The context is as follows:
My model has several BUS connections (featuring expandable connectors) that I would like to switch on or off (**Class Active**). To do this I want to create switches on the BUS that set certain signals to 0. The switch should contain a **White List**. Variables on this **White List** are not set to 0, but passed through instead. This is done in a loop for all n incoming BUS variables.

I have not written any code yet. I do however have a flow chart I created in preparation of implementation. The actual code should be fairly straightforward once I find a get function.
[image: Flow Chart]

The arrow down from **Set 0** to the **gate** seems a bit off, because it looks like I always have to set a variable to 0. What I'm actually doing is either pass the variable through (if on **White List**) to the **Output Connector** or set it 0 (if not on **White List**) and then pass the zero through to the **Output Connector**.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no functions in Modelica that allow you to "introspect" a connector (expandable or otherwise).  Furthermore, you cannot use variables to populate an expandable connector.

When using Modelica, there are a couple of aspects about the language that you need to keep in mind.  The first is that once a model is compiled, the number of variables and equations must remain fixed.  The other is that Modelica is a statically typed language.  As such, the structure of connectors has to be completely known **at compile time**.

What you might be able to do is create a connector that is simply an array of real values (for example) and an associated list of strings.  Then you could map the names to signals or something like that.  You might be able to play some games with changing the mappings during a simulation (by changing the values of the strings and the equations associated with the reals).  But the key is that you need to have a fixed number of equations and variables the whole time.

Comment: The model I use is not meant to be dynamically connected.
The variables passing the switch represent changes in existing variables (i.e. *x_new* is calculated at the receiving end of the connection as *x_new = x_old + delta_x* with *delta_x* passing the switch or being set to 0). I would therefore create an intemediary variable inside my switch that can either have the value of incoming *delta_x* or be set to 0.
Wanting to write a reusable class for my library, rather than hard code variable names for every possible connector, I thought a get function might help...

Comment: ...I'll see if I can write a reusable class using your approach (or maybe some form of wildcard) and update this thread with results.
PS: sorry for the late reply. I am doing this for my student job which I am at 1-2 times a week, so my response time is not always what it should be:)